# Why is IE7 hiding my overflow when, as far as I can tell, all it's containing elements have overflow set to visible?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

If you visit the site in question ([haddongrant.com](http://haddongrant.com/)) and go to the Artwork section, if you click on an image and view it's stack in Safari, Chrome or Firefox you'll notice the images extend up and down the page, eventually disappearing over the edge.

This is what you *should* be seeing. In Internet Explorer 7, however, the overflow gets cut off at some point before it ever gets to the end of the page.

The problem is... I can't tell where! I've had a look and every containing element **should** show overflow. I don't know why IE7 isn't.

Does anyone have any ideas where I might need to add an `overflow-y:visible;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to lie with `position: relative` on #gallery. Removing it fixes the issue, but raises another by adding a horizontal scrollbar. Looks pretty tricky.

This bug appears to be fairly well documented. Check out the following [google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ie7+position+relative+overflow).

I like it better with the overflow being hidden anyway :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I'm just going to keep it hidden with IE. It's not perfect and that REALLY bothers me... But there's apparently nothing I can do about it that would make it work.

Funny how everyone complains about IE6 when IE7 is barely any better...

Answer (score 0):

Is it going underneath the following content - could it be a z-index issue, rather than an overflow?

Comment: I don't think so. It appears to be cutting off at a containing element. The problem is, I don't know which and they all appear to have `overflow-y:visible` defined, either by default or implicitly.

I'm going to make it so they ALL have it implicitly now.